# Invoke Jupyter from within LaTeX

Tags: pythontex

I'd like to be able to write a LaTeX document that contains blocks of code in any of the languages for which I've installed a Jupyter kernel, and have the LaTeX compilation run Jupyter's console on those code blocks and include their output, much like PythonTeX does.

I've tried a web search for this, but all I get are things that have "LaTeX" and "Jupyter" in them but aren't related to my needs. 
 Most are about embedding LaTeX in Jupyter (backwards of what I want).  Others automate the conversion of an existing .ipynb file into a full LaTeX document (but I want to skip the .ipynb file altogether and just work in LaTeX).  A search for "Jupyter" on CTAN returns no results.

[I have asked PythonTeX to support this](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/115), but their answer is "yes, but not soon."  Does anyone know if another solution exists now?

Comment: A manual approach could be to use `\immediate\write18` to run the code and save it to a file, and then input the file.

Comment: Right, but of course this is only if you don't want the cells related/connected to one another in any way.  Things like PythonTeX let you do that and many other features.  I was wondering if there was a general solution already built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TexSurgery

**CTAN**: https://ctan.org/pkg/texsurgery (New on CTAN since 2021-07-10)
**Repository**: https://framagit.org/pang/texsurgery

### Example [GAP Jupyter Kernel](https://github.com/gap-packages/JupyterKernel)

I use [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/) to [satisfy](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python_environment.png) requirements

```shell
mkdir demo-texsurgery && cd demo-texsurgery
pipenv install texsurgery pyparsing
```

For installation of Jupyter kernels see the corresponding instructions of the respective kernel, e.g.
https://github.com/gap-packages/JupyterKernel#installation.

Apply manually an unreleased fix for *texsurgery* 0.6.3 (on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/texsurgery/#history) as of March 2023) to allow kernel names with a `-` (here `gap-4`):

https://framagit.org/pang/texsurgery/-/commit/86d8902e3e592371d191d42517dd41eacc21fd5a

Create a demo file

```tex
% file: demo-texsurgery-hello-gap-kernel.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[gap-4]{texsurgery} % specify kernel

\begin{document}
Here comes output of the GAP Jupyter Kernel:

\begin{run}
modtbl:= CharacterTable( "L3(2)" ) mod 2;;
Print( LaTeXStringDecompositionMatrix( modtbl, 1 ) );
\end{run}

\end{document}
```

*texsurgery* pre-processes the document and outputs a new document with replaced parts. You can combine a run of `texsurgery` and `pdflatex` as following (here with `pipenv` prefixed):

```shell
pipenv run texsurgery demo-texsurgery-hello-gap-kernel.tex -pdf --pdflatex-options -synctex=1
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Note, *texsurgery* allows to use several Jupyter kernels in one document which is described here:
https://framagit.org/pang/texsurgery/-/blob/master/docs/source/kernels.md

**ADDITION: TikZ visualisation for primes and twin primes smaller than 2500 with the [GAP Package IntPic](https://github.com/gap-packages/intpic)**

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[gap-4]{texsurgery} % specify kernel
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry} % tikz matrix is too wide

% for the gap package IntPic generating TikZ code
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{plot}
\usepgflibrary{plothandlers}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{runsilent}
LoadPackage("Singular");
LoadPackage("IntPic");
SetPrintFormattingStatus("*stdout*", false);
\end{runsilent}

\begin{document}

\begin{run}
row_length := 100;; # the maximum length of a row
nrows := 25;; # the number of rows; TIMEOUT Error for 50
n := row_length*nrows;;

##compute the primes less than n
# Primes is a GAP variable representing the list of primes less than n
mp := Maximum(Primes);;
newprimes := [];;
while mp < n do
   mp := NextPrimeInt(mp);;
   Add(newprimes, mp);;
od;
small_primes := Union(Primes, newprimes);;

##compute the first element of each pair of twin primes less than n
twins := Filtered(small_primes, p -> IsPrime(p+2));;
rg := [1..n];;
arr := [Intersection(small_primes,rg),[],[],
         Intersection(Union(twins,twins+2),rg),[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
         [],[],[],[],[],[],Difference(rg,small_primes)];;
Print(IP_TikzArrayOfIntegers([1..n],row_length,rec(highlights:=arr,
              cell_width := "6",colsep:="0",rowsep:="0",inner_sep:="2",
              shape_only:="",line_width:="0",line_color:="black!20" )));
\end{run}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I haven't tried this yet, I just read the manual, and it looks like exactly the right tool.  Thank you!  I expect I'll be using it in future projects.